# Getting XY location of text within TextBox/RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net

How to get coordinates of certain character within TextBox and/or RichTextBox?

I will try to explain this through function:

```
Point GetXY(int characterIndex) {
    //do some magic
    return new Point(x, y);
}
```

Idea is to find where selected text is located so Find dialog will not be displayed over this location but moved to side (like Word is doing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GetPostitionFromCharIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getpositionfromcharindex.aspx) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I cannot believe that I missed that one. :)

Comment: Ya honestly until I started working on my RichTextBoxEx control (http://cccontrols.codeplex.com) I had never noticed the Get... methods on TextBoxBase either. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using interop to SendMessage an [EM_POSFROMCHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761631(VS.85).aspx) message.